# Using angular2 in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-forms

Is it possible to mix Angular2 with AngularJS? For example, in an AngularJS app, have a button that, when clicked, displays an Angular2 form. What approach is appropriate? Should I have the app on separate servers or maybe rewrite Angular2 app to AngularJS?

Comment: You cannot! AngularJs and Angular are completely different.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an application in AngularJS, it is possible to use both Angular and AngularJS with the `upgradeModule`.

Take a look to this link: [Upgrading from AngularJS](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-with-ngupgrade)